# Text inside a tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, fonts, italic

I prepared the following document

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            $De = Re\sqrt{\frac{D}{2R_C}}$
            \draw[->] (-1.35,0.4) ..controls (-1.2,1) and (-0.5,1.5) .. (-0.2,1.5) node[right] {Reynolds number};
            \draw[->] (-2.35,0.4) .. controls (-2.35,0.9) and (-2.75,1)   .. (-3.5,0.3) node[left] {Dean number};
            \draw[->] (-0.15,0.3) .. controls (0.3,0.7) and (0.25,-0.4) .. (0.6,-0.3) node[right] {Hydraulic diameter};
            \draw[->] (-0.25,-0.275) .. controls (-0.5,-1)  .. (-1.5,-1) node[left] {Path curvature radius};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which gives,
[image]

But due to the math mode 'De' and 'Re' becomes italic, I don't want that. But if I try `\text{}` for 'De' and 'Re', it is not working. Please help me to change 'De' and 'Re' into a normal text instead of italic.

Also, I am new to tikz. So, is there any other way to create the pictorial definition of each term in a equation as shown in the picture above?

Comment: You can try `\mathrm`: `$\mathrm{De} = \mathrm{Re}\sqrt{\frac{D}{2R_C}}$`.

Comment: Not related but you could have used `tikzmark` to create nodes and draw your arrows.

Comment: I surprised that works at all, text placed directly inside a `tikzpicture` is normally ignored. You should place the equation in a node, like the other text you have in there.

Comment: @JuanCastaño Thanks, it works and it is simple and easy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution using `tikzmark` library and accepting `\text{}`.

[image: tikzmark equation]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\begin{document}
    \tikzset{every node/.style={outer sep=2pt}}

    \[
    \tikzmarknode{De}{\text{De}} = \tikzmarknode{Re}{\text{Re}}\sqrt{\frac{{\tikzmarknode{D}{D}}}{\tikzmarknode{2RC}{2R_C}}}
    \]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \draw[->] (De.north) to[out=90,in=45,looseness=1.5] ($(De)+(-1,0)$) node[left] {Dean number};
        \draw[->] (Re.north) to[out=90,in=180] ($(Re)+(1.2,1.2)$) node[right] {Reynolds number};
        \draw[->] (D.east) to[out=45,in=190] ($(D)+(1.5,-1)$) node[right] {Hydraulic diameter};
        \draw[->] (2RC.south) to[out=-90,in=0] ($(2RC)+(-1.5,-1)$) node[left] {Path curvature radius};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Note that you may need two compilations to make it right, since the nodes have to be computed before arrows could be drawn.